# SignalR just for checking if user is online or not

Tags: signalr, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to ask, if it is a good idea to use SinglR just for knowing if the current user now online or not?

For example I have an small website with log in system, and some where on the side i would like to show the logged in members.

Is this a good idea to use signalr for that?

And if it the case should I then on each page start the connection with hub? (In this case when user navigates on the pages, will be the ReConnected method called on hub, or OnDisconnected and OnConnected)?

I'm just starting with signalr, so curious what ppl think.

Answer (score 1):

I have been investigating the same thing.  From my research, I would say that you COULD do this, but I'm on the fence of whether it's the best way to go about it.  I would expect a LOT of disconnecting, connecting and reconnecting.  If you're persisting this data in a database, you should anticipate a lot of database traffic.  if you're only on a single server though, you could just persist this in memory.

Something to also note is that the ConnectionId changes with each page refresh.  At first, I thought that was dumb because I wanted the connection id to be consistent so i could keep a handle on a user with it.  However, if you open a link in a new tab and then close one of them, you have to still keep the other connection in storage.  If the id was the same you would remove it on disconnect even though the other tab was open, so your user would incorrectly be marked as offline.

However, the other issue that i'm thinking about is that if you're just browsing around the site in a single tab, you will disconnect for a split second between each page load.  So you might run into connection consistency issues with that.

I'd say online presence with signalr is more common to be used for a chat room or game lobby.  So I'd say this is possible, but whether it's a good solution -- i'm unsure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SignalR though there might be better methods to do this. So when a user logs in, logs out or becomes inactive - you would have some sort of message being sent from the client to the server that indicates the change in status. You can store that information in a temporary database and whenever a value in the database changes you can use SignalR to relay that information to all the connected clients.

Comment: To see if a user is online or not, you are probably going to need to have the browser periodically message the server to indicate it is still on a given page. This is client to server messaging/pinging. 
SignalR really excels at the opposite: server to client messaging. Until recently, this usually necessitated some sort of polling by the client, but libraries like SignalR and socket.io make this easier today.

Answer (score 0):

Signalr will get reconnected when the user moves from one page to another page. Whenever a user logs into a website the user security details will be persisted in a cookie assuming you are using Cookiebase authentication. So till the user logs out or session timesout the cookie will be active. So there is no real need for Signalr here.

Comment: hmm, how can an application then know if user is logged off? When he logged in he set remember me, so yeah ...